# Solving equation of form $a = \prod_i^N (c_i e^t + b)^{c_i}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, exponential-function, roots, transcendental-equations

How can I go about solving the following equation for $t$?

$$
\prod_{i=1}^4 p_i^{c_i} = \prod_{i=1}^4 \left(c_i e^{-t}+\frac14\right)^{c_i}
$$

where $p_i \in (0,1)$, $c_i \in [-\frac14, \frac34]$, $\sum_{i=1}^4 p_i = 1$, and $\sum_{i=1}^4 c_i = 0$. In case it helps, I can also add the constraint that the $c_i$ are of the form $c_i = \frac{B_i}{K} - \frac14$, where $B_i, K \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \leq B_i \leq K$.

#### What I've tried so far:

I can solve this in the special cases where the $c_i$ take on only $2$ distinct values (the degenerate 1 distinct value case is trivial):

$$c_1 = 3 \alpha, ~ c_2 = c_3 = c_4 = -\alpha \implies t = \log\frac{4\alpha p_1 + 12 \alpha (p_2 p_3 p_4)^{1/3}}{p_1 - (p_2 p_3 p_4)^{1/3}}$$
$$c_1=c_2=\beta, ~ c_3=c_4=-\beta \implies t = \log\frac{4\beta (p_1 p_2)^{1/2} + 4\beta (p_3 p_4)^{1/2}}{(p_1 p_2)^{1/2} - (p_1 p_2)^{1/2}}$$

I can't find a solution for a general case, though.

Can you help me either (a) find a general analytical solution for $t$ or (b) prove that no such general solution exists?

Comment: Your question is too general. You evidently need numerical methods.

Comment: @JeanMarie Fair point; I had considered the possibility that no such general solution existed but hadn't discussed that it my question. I'll edit the question to reflect your feedback.

Comment: Your issue is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^4 \underbrace{c_i \log(\frac{c_i x + b}{p_i})}_{f_i(x)}=0$ with $x:=e^{-t}$; Thus, at least qualitatively, you can draw the graphical representation of the four $f_i$s and look if there exists values of $x$ such that their sum is $0$ in $[0,1]$.